# Select last good value for each day with multiple rows for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datatable laid out as:

| Volume | Datestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 2024-01-02 00:05:28 |
| 550 | 2024-01-01 12:00:50 |
| 560 | 2024-01-01 11:40:20 |
| 580 | 2024-01-01 11:24:38 |
| 620 | 2024-01-01 00:04:37 |
| 630 | 2023-12-31 00:04:15 |
| 0 | 2023-12-31 00:04:09 |
| 640 | 2023-12-31 00:04:12 |
| 0 | 2023-12-30 00:04:09 |
| 730 | 2023-12-29 14:04:09 |

And I am trying to extract the last good value (IE no 0 values) for the last datestamp of the day. It should therefore give:

| Volume | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | 2024-01-02 |
| 580 | 2024-01-01 |
| 630 | 2023-12-31 |
| 730 | 2023-12-29 |

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Volume]
FROM Mytable
WHERE [Datestamp] IN (
    SELECT MAX (Datestamp)
    FROM Mytable
    GROUP BY DATE(Datestamp)
)
```

But i get 'Date' is not a recognized built-in function name. If i comment out the group by Date(Datestamp) i just get a blank result

Comment: why 580 for 2024-01-01? last i checked 550 2024-01-01 12:00:50 is after 2024-01-01 11:24:38

Answer (score 1):

Exclude 0 values and find last timestamp per day using `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
    select
        volume,
        cast(datestamp as date) as date,
        row_number() over (partition by cast(datestamp as date) order by datestamp desc) as rn
    from t
    where volume > 0
) as x
where rn = 1
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Still same problem 'date' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: Thanks, tags modified and code works. Thank you

Comment: Question, if it had an extra column say "Shop" which gave Shop A or Shop B, how would you get it for each shop?

Comment: Add additional columns to the partition by clause, just like you would add to a group by.

Comment: Your adjusted code now fails, you must change a to be rn

You also have to add the shop_ID to the select part as as well as the partition to make it work and label.
---
select *
from (
    select
        volume,
shop_ID as shop,
        cast(datestamp as date) as date,
        row_number() over (partition by cast(datestamp as date), shop_ID order by datestamp desc) as rn
    from t
    where volume > 0
) as x
where rn = 1
order by 2 desc
---